# How to find audio file link behind javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, npm, puppeteer

I'm trying to figure out if I can programmatically find a link to an pronunciation audio clip on a site (creating personal language learning Anki deck). The exact site is:

https://islenskordabok.arnastofnun.is/ord/45876

Clicking on "Framburður" plays the audio clip and I can also see the URL to the ogg file in my browser's inspector (it's loaded even without clicking the button). I've verified that the link is a full URI and leads me to the correct file as well. I'm not sure how to access it since it seems to be behind some javascript code.

I've been reading through Puppeteer's documentation and trying to figure out how I might find a way to get it to display the link so that I can then use another program to download it, but I haven't found anything that would work.

If anyone knows how I could accomplish this or has any ideas on things that I could try, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: So using something along the lines of `document.querySelectorAll("audio > source[type='audio/ogg']")[0].src` is not working? If that's the case, have you tried putting it inside a `setInterval` or otherwise waiting for a while, because the audio component might be loaded later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the audio source is not loaded directly on the audio element, and rather on the children nodes called `source`, you can't access it via `document.querySelector('audio').src`.

The right way to do it is to get the child element and access the source from there, but since Puppeteer is a middle man between Node and the DOM, you have to use `eval` to get the child element, and using Vanilla JavaScript, you can get the same effect by using what fiddlingaway suggested:

```
document.querySelectorAll("audio > source[type='audio/ogg']")[0].src
```